# PHP Post Twitter API with username and password

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been looking at examples of Twitter Api and none of the onces I've been able to find use the user's username and password.

Basically, I want to be able to tell the code the account that I want to log into in order to post a tweet.

So basically I want the user to be able to post into different accounts by changing the username and password.

Doe anyone know if the api settings oauth_access_token, etc can carry a username and password so it tells the api what account to post to?

Otherwise, does anyone have any idea on where to start?

Answer (score 3):

> I have been looking at examples of Twitter Api and none of the onces I've been able to find use the user's username and password.

Collecting a user's password is a violation of the Twitter TOS.

You should be using [their OAuth authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth) to get an access token, which can be used essentially like a username and password to access that user's account.

Comment: But is there no way to dictate which twitter account the user logs in if the user has several? For example, there are some plugins where, if the user is already logged into twitter it will just post. I want the user to be able to switch. I guess I'm a bit confused with twitter and oath :o/

Comment: You can let the user sign in to multiple Twitter accounts by appending `force_login` parameter (see this documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/get/oauth/authorize). You will have to remember all corresponding OAuth access tokens and their secrets in your database, and let the user select from.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OAuth discussed in @ceejayoz's reply, the Twitter API also provides support for **xAuth.** xAuth provides a way for desktop and mobile applications to exchange a username and password for an OAuth access token. Once the access token is retrieved, xAuth-enabled developers should dispose of the login and password corresponding to the user.

xAuth access is restricted to approved applications. If your application is a desktop or mobile application that has no other recourse but to utilize xAuth, send a detailed request to https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform. Include the name of your application, the consumer key, the application ID (if available), and a summary of how xAuth is best-suited for your application.

Find [more information about xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/xauth) in the Twitter API docs.

Comment: Good answer, +1. I believe Twitter rejects pretty much any xAuth application these days, though - they never allowed it for webapps, and desktop apps are being encouraged to use either the built-in OS integration or oAuth.